# Ajax Not working Properly.

Tags: php, ajax, parsing

i am trying to register customer and want live checking of email is registered with us or not. mobile number is registered with us, i am not getting the required result in both the event it give me same result if its registered of not. can you please help me. result in both event is  ///"Already Registered with this E-mail";

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$sellerEmail =$_POST['name'];

    $query_verify_mob= new ParseQuery("Vyapari");
    $query_verify_mob->EqualTo("sellerEmail", $sellerEmail);
    $result=count($query_verify_mob);




if($result ==1)
{
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>Already Registered with this E-mail...</span>";


}
else
{     
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>Email ID is Available...</span>"; 
}}.
```

Comment: More input is needed to answer. What does the `New ParseQuery`? does it implement `Countable` ?

Answer (score 0):

0 input in what ParseQuery is, aniway u must just check the count of emails with that input email.

Instead of $result == 1 u should use $result > 0.